# IF EXIST...ELSE not executing as expected IF EXIST run chrome ELSE run IE

Tags: batch-file

I wrote this so I don't need to dawdle around each time I go to a new computer to work on java. I'm sure by reading it you can tell what I am trying to achieve so I wont bore you with the details.

The main problem being she doesn't work ;p I'm following the syntax guide lines from here     --> http://ss64.com/nt/if.html <-- when I click on the bat I see the terminal screen run the script but nothing happens.

Excuse my ignorcence if its something basic but this is close to the first time I needed a batch file.

```
IF EXISTS C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
    (
    chrome
    sleep1
    start "javatut" "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html"
    start "javaapi" "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/"
    )
ELSE 
    (
    iexplore
    sleep1
    start "javatut" "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html"
    start "javaapi" "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/"
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you're not following the syntax guidelines exactly.  The multiline If/Else requires that the open close brackets be on the same line as the If and Else not separate lines.  Unlike Java, batch files do care about white space.

```
IF EXISTS C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe (
    chrome
    sleep1
    start "javatut" "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html"
    start "javaapi" "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/"
) ELSE (
    iexplore
    sleep1
    start "javatut" "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html"
    start "javaapi" "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/"
)
```

I'm assuming that `{USER}` is just a place holder for your example, since that wouldn't be valid batch syntax.  The correct syntax for a variable is `%USER%` if that is what you meant.

Also you should try running the  batch file from a command line.  In that case the syntax errors will be printed to the screen - rather than having the command window automatically close.

Comment: Ahh cool thanks that and I spellt exists instead of exist fixed it. I was just writing {USER} to say a user however, I will use the %USER% syntax though very handy :). Thanks for your help.